# Is it possible to make type abbreviations with member constraints?

Tags: f#, type-alias

```
type FFRec<'state when 'state: (member Tape: Stack<unit -> unit>)
                   and 'state: (member Mem: ObjectPool)
                   and 'state: (member Str: CudaStream)
                   and 'state: (member Workspace: Workspace)
                   and 'state: (member IsInferenceOnly: bool)> =
    {
    W: d2M
    b: d2M
    a: d2M -> 'state -> d2M * 'state
    }
```

It is possible to replace all those member constraints with an interface, but a small problem with that approach is that the compiler is not smart enough to realize that if I have a function like this for example:

```
let inline reluInitializer (state: ^state) (a: ^a)  =
    let scale = (1.0f / sqrt(addDims a |> float32))
    fillRandomUniformMatrix((str state),a,scale,0.0f)
    a
```

It won't realize that `^state` will have to have an interface constraint and give me an inexplicable signature and implementation differ error in the record generic parameter declaration.

If it is at all possible I'd rather use member constraints than explicit interfaces, but I could not find a way to use type abbreviations to make the above constraint declarations shorter. Would that be possible in current F#?

Comment: Look into the keyword `inline`. It is the best approximation F# has for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to use statically resolved type parameters with types.

Statically resolved type parameters are not supported by the CLR, and therefore need to be erased at compile time. This is possible to do with a function by inlining it at the call site and not compiling it down to IL, but a type must have an IL representation, because otherwise you can't have instances of it at runtime.

You should consider expressing your constraints in the form of assessor functions, one for every member. This way, even though your type will compile with an "unacceptable" type argument, the usages of it won't, thus effectively constraining the whole program.

As for the problem you describe with the `^state` parameter in your example, I don't quite see what it is: your function doesn't have any member access in it, so I don't see how it would cause an error related to members.

---

And responding to your question in the comments: no, it is not possible to include member constraints in a type alias for reuse.

Comment: If by accessor function you mean the kind of inlined function such as `let inline dispose v = (^b: (member Dispose: unit -> unit) v)` then I am using them all over the place. What I showed above is just a small part of my 2k LOC library, so I was not sure whether showing the implementation is necessary. Unlike in regular let functions, the compiler requires me to write out the member constraints explicitly in classes and records rather than inferring them itself, so I was really asking whether it is possible to abbreviate type constraints.

Comment: Right now I am trying to do it using inheritance and am getting really unhelpful type errors when using inheritance constraints. Basically, the entire library is inlined and uses statically resolved type parameters for brevity.

Comment: You did not make your question or problem any clearer. Try being more specific. Try providing examples along with desired result and error messages that you get.

Comment: It is difficult to make the example minimalist, but with respect to the inheritance problem, it is easy to make it manifest. If you'd like, take a look at [line 1931 here](https://github.com/mrakgr/Spiral-Bug/blob/inheritance_example/Spiral%20Bug/SpiralV4.fs#L1931). Here is what I get `The signature and implementation are not compatible because the type parameter in the class/signature has a different compile-time requirement to the one in the member/implementation`. This problem does not manifest when I used structural typing instead of inheritance. This is was not my actual question however.

Comment: My actual question was more along the lines of whether it is possible to write something like: `type 'A = 'a when a':(member A: int) and a': (member B: string) and a': (member C: int -> int)` and so on. And then in the first example substitute those 5 member constraints with a single variable. What I was asking is something like a let statement for type constraints so I do not have to repeat them over and over in different places. Interfaces and inheritance provide some of that benefit. I hope that was clear. I was really talking about two related problems in my post.

Comment: Added a line to the answer.

Comment: Well, I expected as much. I am going to have to find a way to formalize my member constraints using inheritance or interfaces perhaps. It is a pity...I might be worth adding the suggestion for this feature to the F# user voice site.

Comment: I think (not sure though) that you may be missing the point. Why do you even use members?

Comment: If what you mean is, why do I use member constraints with F# inlined functions instead of standard OO polymorphism? The reason for that it that the first option is more dynamic. Structural typing is pretty great and it allows me from a low level of abstraction to a higher relatively gracefully compared to the alternatives. For the same reason I use records with higher order function as fields instead of standard classes with virtual method overriding. In F#, I think structural typing is more powerful than the alternatives too. This feature definitely needs to be polished and streamlined more.

Comment: No, I meant the question the other way around: why do you need to use OO-style members instead of functional-style functions, lenses, etc.?

Comment: Suppose I have a record A and B which have a mutable field x of type int. Then if I had a function like `let increment_x (r: ^a)`, how am I supposed to implement it without accessing member functions by using statically resolved type parameters? The only choice is to use an interface (in the case of records) or having the objects inherit from a base type. So the solution would be pretty similar to using statically resolved params except interfaces are bad for type inference and generic parameters escape their scope for even for trivial things.

Comment: I am really using OO style members in a functional manner, much like Haskell typeclasses. F# does not advertise those parts of it much, but a lot of its features really render standard OO practices obsolete.